# Jest on React, local state with useState

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component with:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
reasonSelected: ''});
```

where in the render I got:

```
        { state.reasonSelected === 'other' && (
          <Input
            testID='reasonInput'
            value={state.reasonOther}
            onChangeText={ text => {
              setState({ ...state, reasonOther: text });
            }}
          />
        )}
```

So, if local state.reasonSelected is 'other' I can get rendered that  componente.

I'm trying this test:

```
const otherReasonInput = rendered.getByTestId('reasonInput');
expect(otherReasonInput).toBeTruthy();
```

But in my test, how can I get the `state.reasonSelected` to be actually "other" in order to get Input rendered?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the valid answer, but what I did was this:

```
const pickerReason = rendered.getByTestId('reasonPicker');
// that it comes fron a component that if I change the value to other, will set the state to the desire one, so I want to actually change that values with:
fireEvent.valueChange(pickerReason, 'Otro');
```

Now the setState should be called as I wanted. Of course, I didn't put that part of the code in the original code, but the solution comes to mind after reading some other threads.

By calling to `valueChanges` the setState is called with the value that I pass by parameter, so everything goes ok.